# Crossrider extension, ready code do not run

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, crossrider

I started using crossrider, actuly I have just registered my self

```
/************************************************************************************
This is your Page Code. The appAPI.ready() code block will be executed on every page load.
For more information please visit our docs site: http://docs.crossrider.com
*************************************************************************************/

appAPI.ready(function($) {

    // Place your code here (you can also define new functions above this scope)
    // The $ object is the extension's jQuery object

    alert("My new Crossrider extension works! The current page is: " + document.location.href);
});
```

And this does not alerts me when page loads.

Comment: From the tags, I presume you are referring to Firefox. The code usually works without issue. Do you see any specific errors in your console (Ctrl+Shift+J or Ctrl+Shift+K)? If you provide the extension id, I am happy to test it at my end? [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Extension ID: 63472 - No errors for CTRL+SHIFT+K, but for CTRL+SHIFT+J there were a lot of lines, there where few errors, but I believe none of those was from crossrider

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I tried the extension on FF31/Win7 and it installed and worked as expected. What version of FF and OS are you using? If you prefer, we can continue this discussion via the Crossrider support helpdesk by emailing support@crossrider.com with a reference to this ticket.

Comment: Win7, FF31 I will email, I have not tried it on another computer, but I will soon. I will email you if I get into problems on another computer too.

Comment: It works on another computer both in IE11 and FF31. Looks like it is problem with computer.